# Can native C programs be used in LibGDX?

Tags: c, libgdx

I have a program in C which i would like to call and use it in LibGDX so that i can use it both for android and desktop. So can you suggest me methods to call a C file into LibGDX?

Comment: make sure u dont end up using jni calls in render or update as jni calling seriously effects FPS

Comment: just use basic jni tips to use it on desktop and for using it on android convert it to so file using android native sdk

Comment: I am able to run it as an android application separately, but i want the C fuctionalities into my LibGdx project so that i can use it for cross platforms which also icludes IOS and desktop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, I believe you have an app written in Java that uses Libgdx currently, and you would like to extend that app by including a C library and making calls out to the C library from the Java application.

Libgdx does not provide any special support for third-party libraries, native or Java.  You will have to use the backend platform's APIs to call out to native code (JNI, NDK, etc).

You should be able to add your library to the Android and Desktop backend projects, and access it via a [Platform Interface](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific).  It is probably not possible to use the GWT-backend (unless you have a C to Javascript compiler).  For iOS you would need to build your library for iOS, and then figure out how to link it into the Xamarin (or robovm) build process for your app.  While I'm going to assume this is possible, I suspect neither is easy to accomplish.